# React js add or remove state objects in an array with properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I need to add or remove objects from the state.

State:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scopesUser: [
        {
          scope: "user",
          actions: ["create"]
        },
        {
          scope: "make",
          actions: ["create", "update", "delete"]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

function:

```
 onChangeScope = (scope, action, ev) => {
    let event = ev.target.checked;
    const { scopesUser } = this.state;
    let copyScopes = Object.assign([], scopesUser);
    console.log(scope, action, event, copyScopes);

    let find = copyScopes.filter(obj => {
      return obj.scope === scope;
    });
    let el = Object.assign({}, find[0]);

    if (event === true) {
      if (el.scope === undefined) {
        console.log("creo");
        this.setState(
          prevState => ({
            scopesUser: [...prevState.scopesUser, { scope, actions: [action] }]
          }),
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.scopesUser);
          }
        );
      } else {
        console.log("modifico");
        let actions = [...el.actions];
        actions.push(action);
        actions = actions
          .reduce((a, b) => {
            if (a.indexOf(b) < 0) a.push(b);
            return a;
          }, [])
          .sort();
        let index = copyScopes.findIndex(obj => obj.scope === scope);
        copyScopes[index].actions = actions;

        this.setState(
          {
            scopesUser: copyScopes
          },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.scopesUser);
          }
        );
      }
    } else {
      let actions = [...el.actions];
      actions = actions.filter(item => {
        return item !== action;
      });
      if (actions.length === 0) {
        let scop = copyScopes.filter(ul => {
          return ul.scope != el.scope;
        });
        console.log("rem", el.actions.length);
        this.setState(
          {
            scopesUser: scop
          },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.scopesUser);
          }
        );
      } else {
        let index = copyScopes.findIndex(obj => obj.scope === scope);
        copyScopes[index].actions = actions;
        this.setState(
          {
            scopesUser: copyScopes
          },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.scopesUser);
          }
        );
      }
    }
  };
```

**Add:**

1. If the object does not exist, I add it to the state with the actions.

`this.onChangeScope ("prop", "read", true);`

```
scopesUser: [
        ...,
        {
          scope: "prop",
          actions: ["read"]
        }
      ]
```

2. If the object exists then I only add action to the object with the same name in the array.

`this.onChangeScope ("make", "read", true);`

```
scopesUser: [
        ...,
        {
          scope: "make",
          actions: ["create", "read", "update", "delete"]
        }
      ]
```

Remove:

1. If the object exists, I remove the actions property I passed, if the array is empty I remove the object from the state.

`this.onChangeScope ("user", "create", true);`

```
     scopesUser: [
        {
          scope: "make",
          actions: ["create", "update", "delete"]
        }
      ]
```

I'm having some problems.

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: If you are on latest React, please consider using `useReducer` hook. Your usecase fits nicely there, and it will be much more comfortable for yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this is what you mean:

```js
var object = {demonstration: "firstObject"};
    object.added = {newObject: true};
    object.remove = "This will be treated, as it would be removed";
    object.remove = undefined;
    console.log(object);
    console.log(object.remove);
```

As you can see, you can just define the new state, to add an object.

I don't really know, how to remove Objects, but if you define it as undefined, that should work.

I hope, this is what you ment and it helps you